# Highlight Menu on Current Page

Tags: css, menu, navigation

I don't understand why the menu won't highlight on current page? on .menu ul li a:hover, .active {color: #788d35} If I put "background-color" instead of "color"it will work. How do I highlight just the text if current page is active?

HTML:

```
<section class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="home.html"> HOME </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> illustrations </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> portraits </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> environments </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> sketches </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#"> STORE </a>
              <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://society6.com/ChristiLu" target="_blank"> society6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.redbubble.com/people/christisocool/shop" target="_blank"> redbubble </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> CONTACT </a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  height: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  /*background:orange;*/
}
.menu ul {
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "calibri", "arial";
}
.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid purple;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
.menu ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
/*removes border after 'about'*/

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #854288;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: strong;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover,
.active {
  color: #788d35
  /* <-- if I put "background-color" instead of "color"    it will work. How do I highlight just the text if current page is active? */
}
.menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: white;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
.menu ul li ul li a {
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: According to my test of your code, the text is, indeed, changing color. By "highlight", what did you have in mind?
http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/M8g7Q/

Comment: I meant just the text, not including the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.active` selector is being overruled by the `.menu ul li a` selector. So you can either change `.active` selector to `.menu ul li a.active` or change the color property `color: #788d35;` to `color: #788d35 !important;`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5mpjj/

For more information: http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed .active to .menu ul li a.active just like you said. It works perfect now thanks again!